# find div inside table cell with selector

Tags: jquery, image, selector

I need a little help here if possible, because I can't find the source attritube of an image with a selector

I have already used `$(this).children('someclass')` just before, 
and the one I am trying to locate is in the same table cell next to the other `div`

```
$(".reg_info_body").hide();
$(".reg_info").toggle(function(){
    $(this).children(".reg_info_body").slideDown(100);

    var $bb = $(this).parent().next(".img_uitklapbaar").attr("src");
    alert("source img: " + $bb); // for testing


    }, function(){
        $(this).children(".reg_info_body").slideUp(300);
    }
);
```

```
<tr class="reg_rij">
  <td width="20%"><div class="reg_form_label">Voornaam:</div></td>
  <td width="12%" class="reg_info" > <input type="text" class="reg_invoer" name="voornaam" 
    size="20" maxlength="20" value="<?php if (isset($trimmed['voornaam'])) echo $trimmed['voornaam']; ?>" /></td>
  <td width="4%" class="reg_info">?*</td>
  <td width="64%" class="reg_info"><div class="reg_info_body"><h4>? -: Voornaam [verplicht]</h4><p>
    Vul hier uw voornaam in</p></div>
    <div align="right"><img  class="img_uitklapbaar" src="../images/expand_icon.gif" width="16" height="16" /></div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is that HTML exactly what you have? if so, there is a typo before the src attribute... the (") doesn't belong there.

Comment: oops... I mean there is a space needed between the " and src

Comment: @scunliffe: you can delete your comment and post it again, instead of writing a new one to correct the first one ;)

Comment: maybe,  the typo is the solution. I will try to find it with the children selector then

Comment: var $bb = $(this).children(".img_uitklapbaar").attr("src"); gives
an undefined  error

Comment: var $bb = $(this).children().children(".img_uitklapbaar").attr("src"); was the solution, THANKS

Answer (score 0):

maybe, I have too change it a little bit, but it is not completely accurate

```
var $bb = $(this).parent().find(".img_uitklapbaar").attr("src");
```

I will keep with my previous finding for the moment [see example](http://www.woonbel.nl/registraties/registratie.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the [siblings](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/siblings#expr) method.  Might work for you as well.

Comment: I think,I try'd everything now, possibly not in the right way
That's why I got into trouble, but at least I found it using one method. So, it's good for now, thanks